# Why do I get a Syntax Error: SassError: expected "{"?

Tags: css, sass, sass-loader, dart-sass, sass-maps

The example given by the sass [`map.set` documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps#add-to-a-map) doesn't work, why is that?

```
@use "sass:map";

$font-weights: (
  'regular': 400,
  'medium': 500,
  'bold': 700
);

map.set($font-weights, 'extra-bold', 900);
// ("regular": 400, "medium": 500, "bold": 700, "extra-bold": 900)
map.set($font-weights, 'bold', 900);
// ("regular": 400, "medium": 500, "bold": 900)
```

My `sass` version is `1.32.5`.
The entire error message:

```sh
Syntax Error: SassError: expected "{".
  ╷
9 │ map.set($font-weights, 'extra-bold', 900);
  │                                          ^
  ╵
  src\assets\styles\variables.scss 9:42  @import
  src\assets\styles\main.scss 4:9        root stylesheet
```

I expect the map to be set without throwing errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem 1** (If you *are* using `map.set`, please skip to problem 2)

Actually, I was using `map-set` the whole time, I thought `map-set` is the same as `map.set`, turned out it's not.

In Sass's doc [Built-In Modules](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules):

> Before the Sass module system was introduced, all Sass functions were globally available at all times. **Many functions still have global aliases (these are listed in their documentation)**. The Sass team discourages their use and will eventually deprecate them, but for now, they remain available for compatibility with older Sass versions and with LibSass (which doesn’t support the module system yet).

And [`map.set`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map#set) doesn't have a global `map-set` like [`map.merge`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map#merge) does (`map-merge`).

**Problem 2**

Also, I thought `map.set` would act like JavaScript's `Map.prototype.set()`, by which you set a map like `map.set(key, value)` without assigning it to a variable will work. In Sass, I had to do:

```
@use "sass:map";

$map: ();
$map: map.set($map, key, value);
```

**Why `@debug` "didn't work" for me**

Mostly I'm using Sass under the `vue-cli` environment. Sass's `@debug` syntax "never had" any output visually, it turned out they're *actually* outputted, I just have to scroll up a bit:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If an error in your code is still occurring, you might do the same stupid mistake as I did.

#### Solution

Just assign the return value to some variable.

#### Explanation

`map.set` actually returns a new map with updated values **and it is not assigned to a variable**, so the following code will throw the error `SassError: expected "{".`:

```
@using 'sass:map';

$test: (
  foo: 23,
  bar: ()
);

map.set($test, bar, baz, 5);
```

... because on line 8 (`map.set($test, bar, baz, 5);`) set function will return new map (`(foo: 23, bar: (baz: 5))`) and it is not valid sass syntax, so the situation will be the same as you will write the following code:

```
@using 'sass:map';

$test: (
  foo: 23,
  bar: ()
);

(foo: 23, bar: (baz: 5));
```